# Configuring auto-completion with TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

TeXstudio does a pretty good job with autocompletion. For example, when I type `\eqref{`, it already comes with suggestions, see the example below.

[image: TeXstudio does the auto-completion perfectly]

However, suppose that I don't want to use `\eqref` but a customized command using `newcommand` (I do this so that I can quickly switch to different styles, e.g., some for journals/conferences "Eq. (1)" is needed, whereas sometimes "(1)" suffices). In this case, TeXstudio does not do the auto-completion, see the example below.

[image: TeXstudio does not do the auto-completion]

**Is it possible to configure TeXstudio such that it does the auto-completion for custom commands that require a reference?**

Note that one option is to redefine `\eqref` using `\renewcommand`, but I'm looking for another way so that I can use if for many more commands, not just for `\eqref`.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\alternative}[1]{Eq.~(\ref{#1})}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:emc2}
        E = mc^2
    \end{equation}
    I can refer to the equation using \eqref{eq:emc2} and using \alternative{eq:emc2}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For that, you will have to make use of a custom .cwl file (which, afaik, requires a recent version of TeXstudio).

Create a file, let's say `mycwl.cwl`, in either `%appdata%\texstudio\completion\user` or `.config/texstudio/completion/user` according to your system.

In it, place the following line:

```
\alternative{label}#r
```

and save it. Technically, you can put anything meaningful in the argument, but some terms are reserved and have special meaning. And, as you wish TeXstudio to recognize a label there, you require one of those, namely `label`. The comment at the end of the line tells TeXstudio what kind of command yours is. `#r` stands for `this command declares a reference like "\ref{key}"`. For further commands, just add a new line to your `mycwl.cwl`.

Then, in TeXstudio, go to `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Completion` and check `mycwl.cwl` on the list (**crucial**). And that's about it.

[image: use of custom command in TeXstudio]

For more details on customizing autocompletion with cwl files, check the [TeXstudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html), section "4.13 Description of the cwl format".

A tip: If the manual seems complicated, and you'd like to emulate the behavior of some command's autocompletion you like, you might want to download the sourcecode tarball at http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/, unpack it and look at the built-in cwl files in the "completion" folder. From there, you can proceed by means of examples of your commands of interest.

Comment: Wow, that would have taken me hours to figure this out (if I ever succeeded). Thanks, it works like a charm!

Comment: @EdG, glad to hear. Btw, it would have been kind of you if you had posted your MWE as code, rather than image, so that you did not leave to others the work of retyping. I still think it is a good idea for you to add it to the question.

Comment: Oh oops, that's stupid from me. Will add it now! Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @COTO, thanks for the edit, I indeed missed the typo.

Comment: off topic: Do you know about `\eqref{}` which inserts `( )` automatically?

Comment: @Sigur, I don't really get the scenario you are picturing. Afaik, `\eqref{}` only takes one argument between braces, why would autocomplete add parentheses there? You are thinking of something like `\eqref{(label)}`? I suppose it can be done, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @gusbrs, observe I wrote *off topic*. It is just an improvement. Instead of `\newcommand{\alternative}[1]{Eq.~(\ref{#1})}` one can use `\newcommand{\alternative}[1]{Eq.~\eqref{#1}}`, so `()` will be inserted automatically **in output**.

Comment: @Sigur, oh, now I see. In this case, imho the best improvement for the definition of this particular command is not to use it and go straight to cleveref, as suggested by samcarter. I tried to address only the issue of autocompletion in the answer, all else was inherited from the OP. But if you think the use of `\eqref` there would be better practice, please be my guest to edit.

Comment: It is just my comment. Usually `\eqref{}` is used in this case, but only if wished.

Comment: @Sigur, consider it done. :)

Comment: @Sigur, thanks for the comment. I wrote the `\newcommand` stuff more for the sake of having an example, but I think you are right in that using `\eqref` makes more sense. Anyway, I am now using `cleveref`, which is even better :)

Comment: +1 One of the greatest answer ever! This trick is solving one of my century-old problem with texstudio. In this way, I can manage ALL the other auto-completion preferences!

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to use the `cleveref` package instead of manually defining commands for all possible types of labels.

- `cleveref` will automatically insert the appropriate string based on the type of label you are referring to
- texstudio automatically suggest possible labels

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:emc2}
        E = mc^2
    \end{equation}
    I can refer to the equation using \eqref{eq:emc2} and using \cref{eq:emc2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the question in abstract form, but that is certainly good advice! (+1)

Comment: Btw, you see I finally updated my TS, stimulated by an answer of yours not long ago.  :)

Comment: @gusbrs :) I wish you a lot of fun with your updated TS! I am eagerly waiting for version 2.12.8 because of this commit: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/commit/3b6c0f3c94e63f2a21725e4194f75b8932dffc71

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for your answer. Though it is not an exact answer to my question, it's a very good advice (+1). I did not know of cleverref, but now I do :)

Comment: hahaha! Indeed, the only conceivable reason why this was not part of TS since version 0.1 beta is that `tikzducks` was not available then.  :)

Comment: I've never heard of `tikzducks` before, but it is pretty awesome :P

Comment: @EdG Be careful they can be addictive :)

Comment: @samcarter I know, they are addictive. My personal reports now have at the bottom of the page a duck with a sign post with the page number (i.e. `\fancyfoot[C]{\tikz[scale=0.5]{\duck[signpost=\thepage]}}`). Really well done!

Comment: @EdG Thanks! You could also try `\fancyfoot[C]{\shuffleducks\tikz[scale=0.5]{\duck[signpost=\thepage,\randomhead]}}` :)

Comment: @samcarter That is even better! You made my day :)

Comment: @EdG I'm glad you like the ducks!