# Can TeXstudio be configured to highlight labels in custom commands?

Tags: texstudio

TeXstudio helpfully applies special formatting to the argument(s) of `\ref{}`, `\pageref{}`, etc., recognizing them as references to labels.

I have a custom command, `\Eq{}`, which accepts a single argument and produces a `\ref` with appropriate syntax for various journals, e.g. "Eq. 5", "(5)", etc.

Of course, TeXstudio doesn't recognize that the argument to `\Eq{}` should be treated as a reference, hence it doesn't apply any formatting, bring up a list of options, check whether the reference is valid, etc.

This seems like a long shot, but I'll ask anyway: is there any way to get TeXstudio to treat my `\Eq{}` command like `\ref{}`, at least in terms of special formatting?

Comment: Would https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414281/configuring-auto-completion-with-texstudio help?

Comment: @samcarter Indeed. It appears to do exactly what I need. Thanks for the link.