# File browser autocompletion for custom command

Tags: texstudio

If I type `\input{` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in TeXStudio, I get a really nice file-browser-style autocomplete box which can help me find my file.

If I create my *own* command, like this:

```
\newcommand{\fooinsert}[1]{Foo first! \input{#1}}
```

how can I tell TeXStudio I want the argument to autocomplete with this file browser?

Comment: Do you already know how to use a cwl file for configuring autocomplete?

Comment: see http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION

Comment: Besides the manual, linked by samcarter, you can get a short intro in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414296/105447. The line you are looking for is probably `\fooinsert{file}#i` (untested though).

Comment: @samcarter I've been RTFM'd! [What would John Skeet say](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23629/253241)?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes! That works perfectly. If you'd like to answer, I'll accept. I don't think this quite qualifies as a duplicate of what you've linked to, although that was certainly very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a custom cwl you can achieve that. If you don't have one already, create a file, let's say `mycwl.cwl`, in either `%appdata%\texstudio\completion\user` or `.config/texstudio/completion/user` according to your system.

In it, place the following line:

```
\fooinsert{file}#i
```

Than enable your `mycwl.cwl` in TeXstudio options.

For more details, see [Configuring auto-completion with TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414281/105447) and check the [TeXstudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html), section "4.13 Description of the cwl format".

Comment: Maybe this is bad practice but I put my `.cwl` file in `.config/texstudio` directly. It worked fine.

Comment: I'm not really sure of this, but my hunch is that what changes is the order of loading and thus of precedence. As far as my experience goes with this, the first autocomplete rule given for a certain command is the one that holds. So probably, the `user` is read first allowing you to override default autocompletion rules. But, as you are using it for a custom command anyway, it probably doesn't make a difference. Still, it wouldn't cost much to conform with the software recommended use, would it? Well, it's up to you anyway, of course.