# Automatically numbered examples

Tags: texstudio, automation, examples

I was able to use the following new environment to number the examples automatically quite conveniently  until yesterday when I updated TeXstudio to version 2.12.8. That is, I only needed to type `\begin{in` to get the suggestion of this environment and then hit Enter to insert it to the text body. This trick no longer works. Pleases help.

Thanks in advance.

```
\newenvironment{inlineexample}
{\par\vskip\medskipamount
    \refstepcounter{theorem}%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title example}\translate{Example}~\theexample}:}
{\par\vskip\smallskipamount}
```

Comment: Does this one help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414281/105447

Comment: Does it work if you press `Ctrl+Space` after, say, `\begin{in` (to bring up the autocompleter)?

Comment: No, Ctrl+Space did not help.

Comment: @gusbrs  The solution in the link you refer works! Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gusbrs. The solution in the link @gusbrs referred works! I re-posted the link below for those who need it.

[Configuring auto-completion with TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414281/105447)

Answer (score 0):

Please Click on Options->Configure TexStudio and Click 'Completion' from left Pane and check the automatically start completer when typing latex-commands and other preferred options you need.
Now restart TexStudio and try again

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The box was checked. It still does not work, probably because this is not a Latex-defined environment? It was working perfectly fine before the update.

Comment: was it a custom cwl defined by you?

Comment: I found the above environment in this forum. It is not a default latex environment.