# TeXstudio - custom .cls and .sty files

Tags: texstudio

I recent migrated from TeXnicCenter to TeXstudio.

TeXstudio doesnt have independent project sytstem like TeXnicCenter. It just takes control of a master document and calls the child files correctly, however how does it know to include .cls and .sty files while compiling?

I see highlights such as `unrecognized command` which are specific to the custom class (*.cls) and style (*.sty) files I intend to use, including citation style files (*.bst). The document compiles correctly producing the correct output as well. But I don't understand how this should be handled in TeXstudio.

Based on [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands) document, I can turn off inline checking to bypass this.

[image: 1]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for TS to highlight and autocomplete your custom commands. If so, perhaps this will help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414296/105447.

Comment: TeXstudio has nothing to do with compilation except calling the compiler. What you see as highlighting is not based on anything related to the real output or compilation process but to TeXstudio's "knowledge" about packages and their commands.

Comment: @TeXnician So how does other editors like TeXnicCenter automatically obtain "knowledge" of these extra package and commands whose scope is limited to the project?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, sorta in a way. I would expect the IDE to take care of that, but may be I am wrong.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari They do not. Most editors do some regex-based highlighting and just gather information from the log if there's a command that is wrong. I do not know about TeXnicCenter's highlighting, but many other editors simply do pattern matching.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari The only one I know which does it by systematically parsing the files is AUCTeX. Most editors will depend on some style files being provided to get a good job done. TS has those for most of your needs, and If I'm not mistaken also has some capability of automatically generating those, and will recognize a `\newcommand`. But for more elaborate requirements, creating your `.cwl`s is the way to go. And, as mentioned by TeXnician, compilation is independent of whether TS recognizes or not any macro.

Comment: Before learning about `.cwl` files, I just opened the file with my `\newcommand`s or with the packages. TeXstudio recognizes any command it "knows" is there, in order to make him "know", you should present it him, which means, loading `.cwl`, opening the file it is stored, etc.