# Get value of \crefname

Tags: cleveref

Instead of hardcoding `theorem` in citations such as `\cite[theorem xyz]{reference}`, I would like to insert the cleveref theorem format, for consistency with references to theorems in the current document. I suppose this would require retrieving the (possibly default) value of `\crefname`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the name is stored in `\cref@<type>@name` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\theoname}{\cref@theorem@name}
\newcommand{\Theoname}{\Cref@theorem@name}
\newcommand{\theonames}{\cref@theorem@name@plural}
\newcommand{\Theonames}{\Cref@theorem@name@plural}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\cref@theorem@name

\Cref@theorem@name

\cref@theorem@name@plural

\Cref@theorem@name@plural
\makeatother

\cite[\theoname{} xyz]{knuth}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: samcarter, reversed roles today! https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414281/105447  :-)

Comment: @gusbrs Oh, nice coincidence! :)  Always fun to see the different approaches answers can use!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and more, thank you!

Comment: @Rastapopoulos You're welcome!