# Own command for references - TexStudio does not recognize referenced labels

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, texstudio

I'm currently writing a thesis using LaTeX. I have a couple of figures (diagrams) in my document and wanted to reference them in a more convenient way than always writing *"bla in figure \ref{labelname}"*.
So I wrote an own command:
`\newcommand{\reffig}{figure \ref}`

This is working. However, if I use it, TexStudio does not recognize the usage of that label. If I hover the cursor over the label of the figure, it will show 0 references.

Same for labels in chapters with my new command:
`\newcommand{\refsec}[1]{section \ref{#1} - \nameref{#1}}`

Did I do something wrong declaring my commands? Is there a way to get TexStudio to recognize the references?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Either there is a method to teach `TeXStudio` such macros and handle them accordingly or rather switch to the more appropiate `cleveref` package, that automatically detects the type of the reference, i.e. `\cref{foofigure}` will show you `Figure 2.1` etc, i.e. you dont need to remember then, whether you need `\reffig` or `\refsec` etc.

Comment: That's a very handy package! It doesn't do what my second command does, but I'll use it anyway. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I agree with @ChristianHupfer: better use `cleveref`. If you want to configure texstudio instead, you have to create a custom .cwl file, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414281/configuring-auto-completion-with-texstudio for more information

Comment: @Auri: You can easily do `\refsec` with `cleverref` as well, by saying `\newcommand{\ncref}[1]{\cref{#1} - \nameref{#1}}`...